# Is there any function in hive that converts epoch time to standard date?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, epoch

to_date function takes this "1970-11-01 00:00:00" as an input and returns "1970-11-01".

But I have epoch time as an input. How do I convert it to standard date format?

There is a function to convert standard date to unix epoch time but not the other way.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks 
priyank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

```
from_unixtime(bigint unixtime[, string format])
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, in case your epoch time value is a `String` column in your hive table

`SELECT TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(CAST(epoch_string AS BIGINT))) FROM hive_table;`